# Is it possible in AmCharts to make the bars in a serial chart take up full width?

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, amcharts

I am trying to create simple Serial Chart in AmCharts but can't make the bars take up the full width of the container. Is there a way to force this?
[image: Serial Charts - AmCharts]

Interestingly, when I inspect the svg element, it does take up the full width of the parent but the bars inside don't stretch that full length. 
[image: Inspected SVG]

Here's the graph configuration.

```
this.chart = this.AmCharts.makeChart(this.barChart.nativeElement, {
  type: 'serial',
  creditsPosition: 'bottom-right',
  rotate: true,
  resizeCategoryWidth: 10,
  dataProvider: chartData.publishers,
  fontFamily: `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,
            Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif`,
  graphs: [
    {
      fillAlphas: 1,
      lineAlpha: 0,
      lineColor: '#2196f3',
      type: 'column',
      fillColors: '#E2E7EE',
      clustered: false,
      valueField: 'max',
      labelText: '[[value]]',
      labelFunction: function(val) {
        return val.dataContext.count;
      },
      labelPosition: 'right',
      columnWidth: 0.15,
      cornerRadiusTop: 3,
      showBalloon: false
    },
    {
      fillAlphas: 1,
      lineAlpha: 0,
      type: 'column',
      valueField: 'count',
      fillColors: '#2196f3',
      columnWidth: 0.15,
      cornerRadiusTop: 3,
      showBalloon: false
    }
  ],
  chartCursor: {
    categoryBalloonEnabled: false,
    cursorAlpha: 0,
    zoomable: false
  },
  categoryField: 'name',
  categoryAxis: {
    gridAlpha: 0,
    color: '#333',
    axisAlpha: 0,
    fontSize: 12,
    inside: true,
    gridPosition: 'start',
    tickPosition: 'start',
    tickLength: 0
  },
  valueAxes: [
    {
      axisAlpha: 0,
      gridAlpha: 0,
      showLastLabel: false
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: @WhiteHat updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

AmCharts always adds some padding around the chart by default. If you want to expand the  chart more toward the right, set [`marginRight`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#marginRight) to 0 or even a negative number to make the chart take up more space on the right side of the container.  You can also set [`autoMargins`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#autoMargins) to false and fine tune other other margins (top, left, bottom) to your liking.

```js
var chartData = {
  publishers: [{
    name: "Pub-1",
    max: 1,
    count: .5
  },{
    name: "Pub-2",
    max: 1,
    count: .75
  },{
    name: "Pub-3",
    max: 1,
    count: .25
  },{
    name: "Pub-4",
    max: 1,
    count: 1
  }]
}
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: 'serial',
  creditsPosition: 'bottom-left',
  rotate: true,
  autoMargins: false,
  marginLeft: 20,
  marginBottom: 35,
  marginRight: -40,
  resizeCategoryWidth: 10,
  dataProvider: chartData.publishers,
  fontFamily: `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,
            Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif`,
  graphs: [
    {
      fillAlphas: 1,
      lineAlpha: 0,
      lineColor: '#2196f3',
      type: 'column',
      fillColors: '#E2E7EE',
      clustered: false,
      valueField: 'max',
      labelText: '[[value]]',
      labelFunction: function(val) {
        return val.dataContext.count;
      },
      labelPosition: 'right',
      columnWidth: 0.15,
      cornerRadiusTop: 3,
      showBalloon: false
    },
    {
      fillAlphas: 1,
      lineAlpha: 0,
      type: 'column',
      valueField: 'count',
      fillColors: '#2196f3',
      columnWidth: 0.15,
      cornerRadiusTop: 3,
      showBalloon: false
    }
  ],
  chartCursor: {
    categoryBalloonEnabled: false,
    cursorAlpha: 0,
    zoomable: false
  },
  categoryField: 'name',
  categoryAxis: {
    gridAlpha: 0,
    color: '#333',
    axisAlpha: 0,
    fontSize: 12,
    inside: true,
    gridPosition: 'start',
    tickPosition: 'start',
    tickLength: 0
  },
  valueAxes: [
    {
      axisAlpha: 0,
      gridAlpha: 0,
      showLastLabel: false
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```